# My USB mouse is disconnecting and reconnecting randomly and often?

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

I've tried turning off my Surface Pro running Windows 10 from "automatically turning off the power to a USB Root Hub" thru the Device Manager but found it didn't help. I'm running the 64 bit version of windows and was wondering if I switched to the 32 bit version whether it may solve my problem. I don't recall having this problem with earlier versions of Windows. I've been using my Surface Pro in it's Surface Docking Station but no matter which USB port I choose, I get the same result. Has anyone tried this with success..?

How do I switch over from my current 64 bit Windows 10 to the 32 bit version..?

Answer (score 0):

**(1) Switch to 32-bit Windows 10:**  You must back up completely, reinstall Windows 32-bit and install your software and recover documents. I do not recommend this at all. 32-bit is going away over time.

**(2) Mouse:**  Reinstall the Mouse Software if there is mouse software.  Check the batteries and make sure they are fresh.

Consider using a **new, different Mouse**.

**(3) Drivers:**  Update ALL your drivers including BIOS and Power Driver.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware problem, not an OS issue.  First test the mouse on another computer.  Does it have problems with disconnections still?  Then the mouse is most likely faulty.  If it does not, try another mouse in the Surface's USB port.  If it also has disconnection issues, then the port or the USB controller has a fault.  If the mouse works fine, then... use that mouse?